# Plotting all outer borders in custom scheme

Tags: plot, stata

I am writing a custom graph scheme (starting from s2color) and I would like to plot the right and upper outer borders of the graph (as done in s1mono and lean1 by default).

Can you suggest how to do this? I have been looking into the codes of the above mentioned schemes without success. Can you suggest othersources where to learn how to control this graphs features? I cannot find it in any documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to alter the `plotregion()` option like this:

```
sysuse auto
scatter price mpg, scheme(s2mono) plotregion(lcolor(black))
```

To add this to the s2color theme for posterity, create a file called scheme-mys2color.scheme somewhere on your adopath that contains these three lines:

```
#include s2color
label "s2 color with all the borders"
color plotregion_line    black
```

Then

```
tw (scatter price mpg), scheme(mys2color)
```

will produce something like this:

[image]

instead of

[image]